# Any WebRTC client implementation for iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, video, stream, webrtc

Is there **any iOS library/SDK I can use to create a single WebRTC one-to-one video call**?

---

Let's say we will have set up the necessary server environmet suggested at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2HzZkd2A40&feature=youtu.be&t=21m40s

---

Not interested in instant cloud services like OpenTok, OpenPeer, OpenClove, vLine, AddLive, etc. We want to create our own infrastructure, I just want to make a test prototype on iOS. **Also cannot see clearly what is need to be implemented on Javascript side (if any) and on native side**, etc.

Comment: For others looking for this...there is an iOS SDK for your own infrastructure, we built one @ Frozen Mountain, IceLink. (http://www.frozenmountain.com/downloads#icelink...disclaimer: I work there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now, iOS has not implemented the webRTC specifications in their Safari browser. Hence you cannot use webRTC in a UIWebView in iOS.

Reference: http://caniuse.com/#search=webRTC

However you might be able to write your own library that connects to your backend service similar to the OpenTok iOS SDK.

Refrence: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-webrtc